# error in app=window(root) and self.filename

Tags: python, coding-style

I am developing the python code for traffic signal violation detection system but the issue came when I stuck here.
Please help me with it since I cannot be able to rectify with it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUVQJ.png)

Full code is here:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import object_detection as od
import imageio
import cv2

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master: None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.root = Tk()
        self.pos = []
        self.line = []
        self.rect = []
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.counter = 0
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_file)
        file.add_command(label="Exit",command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        analyze = Menu(menu)
        analyze.add_command(label="Region of Interest", command=self.regionOfInterest)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Analyze", menu=analyze)
        self.filename = "E:\antarix\traffic\traffic.jpg"
        self.imgSize = Image.open(self.filename)
        self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imgSize)
        self.w, self.h = (1366, 768)
        self.canvas = Canvas(master = root, width=self.w, height=self.h)
        self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, image=self.tkimage, ANCHOR='nw')
        self.canvas.pack()
        
    def open_file(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.filename)

        reader = imageio.get_reader(self.filename)
        fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps'] 

        ret, image = cap.read()
        cv2.imwrite('E:\antarix\traffic\traffic.jpg', image)

        self.show_image('E:\antarix\traffic\traffic.jpg')


    def show_image(self, frame):
        self.imgSize = Image.open(frame)
        self.tkimage =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imgSize)
        self.w, self.h = (1366, 768)

        self.canvas.destroy()

        self.canvas = Canvas(master = root, width = self.w, height = self.h)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.tkimage, anchor='nw')
        self.canvas.pack()

    def regionOfInterest(self):
        root.config(cursor="plus") 
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.imgClick) 

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def imgClick(self, event):

        if self.counter < 2:
            x = int(self.canvas.canvasx(event.x))
            y = int(self.canvas.canvasy(event.y))
            self.line.append((x, y))
            self.pos.append(self.canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", tags="crosshair"))
            self.pos.append(self.canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", tags="crosshair"))
            self.counter += 1

        # elif self.counter < 4:
        #     x = int(self.canvas.canvasx(event.x))
        #     y = int(self.canvas.canvasy(event.y))
        #     self.rect.append((x, y))
        #     self.pos.append(self.canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", tags="crosshair"))
        #     self.pos.append(self.canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", tags="crosshair"))
        #     self.counter += 1

        if self.counter == 2:
            #unbinding action with mouse-click
            self.canvas.unbind("<Button-1>")
            root.config(cursor="arrow")
            self.counter = 0

            #show created virtual line
            print(self.line)
            print(self.rect)
            img = cv2.imread('E:\antarix\traffic\traffic.jpg')
            cv2.line(img, self.line[0], self.line[1], (0, 255, 0), 3)
            cv2.imwrite('E:\antarix\traffic\copy.jpg', img)
            self.show_image('E:\antarix\traffic\copy.jpg')

            ## for demonstration
            # (rxmin, rymin) = self.rect[0]
            # (rxmax, rymax) = self.rect[1]

            # tf = False
            # tf |= self.intersection(self.line[0], self.line[1], (rxmin, rymin), (rxmin, rymax))
            # print(tf)
            # tf |= self.intersection(self.line[0], self.line[1], (rxmax, rymin), (rxmax, rymax))
            # print(tf)
            # tf |= self.intersection(self.line[0], self.line[1], (rxmin, rymin), (rxmax, rymin))
            # print(tf)
            # tf |= self.intersection(self.line[0], self.line[1], (rxmin, rymax), (rxmax, rymax))
            # print(tf)

            # cv2.line(img, self.line[0], self.line[1], (0, 255, 0), 3)

            # if tf:
            #     cv2.rectangle(img, (rxmin,rymin), (rxmax,rymax), (255,0,0), 3)
            # else:
            #     cv2.rectangle(img, (rxmin,rymin), (rxmax,rymax), (0,255,0), 3)

            # cv2.imshow('traffic violation', img)
            
            #image processing
            self.main_process()
            print("Executed Successfully!!!")

            #clearing things
            self.line.clear()
            self.rect.clear()
            for i in self.pos:
                self.canvas.delete(i)

    def intersection(self, p, q, r, t):
        print(p, q, r, t)
        (x1, y1) = p
        (x2, y2) = q

        (x3, y3) = r
        (x4, y4) = t

        a1 = y1-y2
        b1 = x2-x1
        c1 = x1*y2-x2*y1

        a2 = y3-y4
        b2 = x4-x3
        c2 = x3*y4-x4*y3

        if(a1*b2-a2*b1 == 0):
            return False
        print((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2))
        x = (b1*c2 - b2*c1) / (a1*b2 - a2*b1)
        y = (a2*c1 - a1*c2) / (a1*b2 - a2*b1)
        print((x, y))

        if x1 > x2:
            tmp = x1
            x1 = x2
            x2 = tmp
        if y1 > y2:
            tmp = y1
            y1 = y2
            y2 = tmp
        if x3 > x4:
            tmp = x3
            x3 = x4
            x4 = tmp
        if y3 > y4:
            tmp = y3
            y3 = y4
            y4 = tmp

        if x >= x1 and x <= x2 and y >= y1 and y <= y2 and x >= x3 and x <= x4 and y >= y3 and y <= y4:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def main_process(self):

        video_src = self.filename

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_src)

        reader = imageio.get_reader(video_src)
        fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']    
        writer = imageio.get_writer('E:\antarix\traffic\output.mp4', fps = fps)
            
        j = 1
        while True:
            ret, image = cap.read()
           
            if (type(image) == type(None)):
                writer.close()
                break
            
            image_h, image_w, _ = image.shape
            new_image = od.preprocess_input(image, od.net_h, od.net_w)

            # run the prediction
            yolos = od.yolov3.predict(new_image)
            boxes = []

            for i in range(len(yolos)):
                # decode the output of the network
                boxes += od.decode_netout(yolos[i][0], od.anchors[i], od.obj_thresh, od.nms_thresh, od.net_h, od.net_w)

            # correct the sizes of the bounding boxes
            od.correct_yolo_boxes(boxes, image_h, image_w, od.net_h, od.net_w)

            # suppress non-maximal boxes
            od.do_nms(boxes, od.nms_thresh)     

            # draw bounding boxes on the image using labels
            image2 = od.draw_boxes(image, boxes, self.line, od.labels, od.obj_thresh, j) 
            
            writer.append_data(image2)

            # cv2.imwrite('E:/Virtual Traffic Light Violation Detection System/Images/frame'+str(j)+'.jpg', image2)
            # self.show_image('E:/Virtual Traffic Light Violation Detection System/Images/frame'+str(j)+'.jpg')

            cv2.imshow('Traffic Violation', image2)
            
            print(j)

            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                writer.close()
                break

            j = j+1

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("%dx%d"%(535, 380))
root.title("Traffic Violation")

root.mainloop()
```

I tried downloading the other package in order to remove the error as I saw on the google but unfortunately nothing happened to the error.

Comment: You shouldn't use  "\" in paths (it denotes escape sequences), in any case you should escape it ("\\") or use raw strings, but it is better to just use `/`: `self.filename = "E:/antarix/traffic/traffic.jpg"`